# MATLAB: Area and centre of mass of a plotted figure

Tags: matlab

I have made a function that allows a user to draw several points and interpolate those points. I want the function to calculate the centre of mass using this vector :
[image: Omega is part of R^n]

I think I should therefore first calculate the area of the figure (I drew this example to illustrate the function output). I want to do this using Green's theorem [image]
[image]

However since I'm quite a beginner in MATLAB I'm stuck at how to implement this formula in order to find the centre of mass. I'm also not sure how to get the data as my output so far is only the x- and y cordinates of the points.

```
function draw
fig = figure();
hax = axes('Parent', fig);
axis(hax, 'manual')
[x,y] = getpts();

M = [x y]

T = cumsum(sqrt([0,diff(x')].^2 + [0,diff(y')].^2));

T_i = linspace(T(1),T(end),1000);

X_i = interp1(T,x',T_i,'cubic');
Y_i = interp1(T,y',T_i,'cubic');

plot(x,y,'b.',X_i,Y_i,'r-')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Center Of Mass for a 2D coordinate system should just be the `mean` of the interpolated x-coordinates and y-coordinates. The Interpolation should give you evenly spaced coordinates which you can use to your advantage. So simply add to your existing function:

```
 CenterOfMass= [mean(X_i),mean(Y_i)]
 plot(x,y,'b.',X_i,Y_i,'r-')
 hold on
 plot(CenterOfMass(1),CenterOfMass(2),'ro')
```

should give you the center of mass assuming that all points are weighted equally.